# Dynamic data in the _layout.cshtml template to be available on all pages that use this template

Tags: c#, razor-pages

Firstly I clarify that I am not directly using MVC, but rather Razor Pages.

I'm thinking of the best approach to get dynamic data (database) in the _Layout.cshtml template so that they are available on all pages:

**1)** My first option would be to create a PartialView, let's call it _Header.cshtml with the following test content:

```
   @page
    @model _HeaderModel
    <div id = "header">
        @ Model.HeaderMessage
    </ div>
```

And in the _Layout.cshtml template use:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync ("_ Header", new _HeaderModel ())
```

However, this causes the error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", Which I do not really understand, since when passing in the method an instance of new _HeaderModel ()

should not work? If I do not specifies the Model error occurs between _IndexModel and _HeaderModel: ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type _HeaderModel.

Would this be a good approach? If so, why not?

**2)** In my view, my second option would be to create a PageModel base with properties that would be used by all PagesModel that they inherited from PageModel base.

Any kind suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a Visual Studio bug, even though I explicitly add a PartialView, Visual Studio includes @page in the PartialView and that is what was causing the error.

_Header.cshtml

> @page //Removed

```
         @model _HeaderModel

         <div id="header">
             @Model.HeaderMessage
         </div>
```

Now it works

_Layout.cshtml

```
@await Html.PartialAsync ("_ Header", new _HeaderModel ())
```